# Cannot apply custom class to hamburger-react Component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, hamburger-menu

I'm building a website using Gatsby and React-Bootstrap. I added an hamburger-react (https://hamburger-react.netlify.app) component in the navbar to have an animated hamburger-icon instead of the default one from bootstrap.

The problem is that it's still displayed in large screen, while I would like it to show just on smaller screens. I tried to use a mediaquery breakpoint in css (using css modules), but it looks like I can't apply a customized class on the Hamburger component.

Here's my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

import {
    burger
} from "./layout.module.css";
import Hamburger from 'hamburger-react';


const Menu = () => {
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false)

    return (
        <Hamburger toggled={isOpen} toggle={setOpen} className={burger} />
    )
};

export default Menu;
```

We want to apply the class to the Hamburger component with `className={burger}`. The class name from the css component should be `.burger`. But the only class that is applied to the final HTML element is `hamburger-react`, as you can see on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T14hR.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you create a parent div and give it the className "burger"?